# Tagging text using tags stored in database

Tags: php, mysql, tagging

in my new PHP project, I'm going to get a large amount of text as input.

And I have hundreds of tags stored in my mySQL database:

```
|  id   |       tag        |
+-------+------------------+
|   1   |       Halo       |
|   2   |       LIMBO      |
|   3   |    Super Mario   | 
|   3   | Metal Gear Solid |  <-- multiple words as single tag
```

The inputs are also stored in mySQL, before being processed.

How can I check each input for these tags? using `explode(' '` ? `strpos()` ? `LIKE '%TAG1%' OR LIKE '%TAG2%'` ? ...   how can I gain maximum performance with PHP and mySQL?

Thanks

P.S.

How about an input in HTML format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For maximum coincidence set FULLTEXT-index to field `tag`. Then in query use next design :

```
    SELECT * FROM `tags`
    WHERE MATCH(tag) AGAINST (YOUR_INPUT_VALUE)
```

Read [Full-Text Search Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html)

Comment: additionally read about regular expressions

Comment: @SamD I know them more or less, how can they be helpful here? like `strpos` method ?

Comment: @Webinan regular expressions are much more powerful. They can do a lot of text manipulation and extract strings on the database side. There are books about the subject. For example you can have a tag "mysql-database" and you can extract mysql and database and relate them to those tags as well